# Comparing inter-rater agreement between classes of raters with only two ratings per object

Tags: agreement-statistics

In order to decide whether semi-experts can replace experts in my setting, I am interested in comparing ratings of the same objects that were done by two raters from 2 different groups (semi-expert, and experts).

1. My dataset (which is from real data, not a designed experiment) includes two ratings per object from each raters group (semi-experts, experts).
2. There are no fixed semi-expert and expert pairs. One semi-expert works with different experts over time.
3. The number of raters in each group is different (20 in one, 40 in the other).
   [image]

The answer given by the semi-expert and expert is (blinded from each other): 1=yes, 2=no.

I have difficulties finding a model since the semi-experts and experts are not working in fixed pair, while there each object is only rated twice.

Is there any model you recommend me to use?

Comment: How can "rating" be yes/no answer?

Comment: Thank you, I hope this will clarify what I mean:
Both, the semi-experts and experts rate each object in category 1, category 2 or category 3. In case an object is rated in category 1, the object will be referred. I transformed the rating therefore into: is a referral advised?  1=yes, 2 or 3=no. To simply this, I explained it as 1=yes and 2=no only.